# Typescript property concat does not exist

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

My code works as expected but Typescript obviously has an issue with something I have done and I would like to understand what it is. Typescrpt is reporting the following errors:

[image]

Below is the working code.

```
getZones() {
  this.spinner.show();
  this.zonesService.getZonesByUserId(this.userId)
    .mergeMap(zones => Observable.from(zones))
    .mergeMap(zone => this.zonesService.getAssociations(zone['id'], '/team')
      .catch(() => Observable.of(null))
      .map(team => {
        if (team['team']) {
          return Object.assign({}, zone, { teamName: team['team']['name'] });
        } else {
          return zone;
        }
      })
    )
    .mergeMap(zone => this.zonesService.getAssociations(zone['id'], '/site')
      .catch(() => Observable.of(null))
      .map(site => {
        if (site['site']) {
          return Object.assign({}, zone, { siteName: site['site']['name'] });
        } else {
          return zone;
        }
      })
    )
    .reduce((zones, zone) => {
      return zones.concat(zone);
    }, [])
    .subscribe(
      _data => {
        this.zones  = _data
          .map(zone => {
            if (zone['personal']) {
              this.personalZone = zone;
              this.personalZone['name'] = 'My Personal Zone';
              this.personalZone['teamName'] = '';
            }
            return zone;
          })
          .filter(zone => {
            return zone['personal'] !== true;
          })
          .map(zone => {
            if (zone['siteName'] === undefined) {
              zone['siteName'] = 'NO_SITE_NAME';
            }
            return zone;
          });

        if (this.zones && this.personalZone !== null) {
          this.zones.unshift(this.personalZone);
        }

        this.loading = false;
        this.spinner.hide();
      },
      _error => {}
    );
};
```

The error showed up after I added the if conditions within the map methods. Prior to the addition of those conditions my code was as follows:

```
.map(team => {
  return Object.assign({}, zone, { teamName: team['team']['name'] });
})

.map(site => {
  return Object.assign({}, zone, { siteName: site['site']['name'] });
})
```

The conditions were required to deal with instances of the server failing to return the requested object. Now Typescript seems to have an issue with the code. For sure the zones parameter in the reduce function is an array and for sure the _data value is also an array. For some reason Typescript thinks these are objects.

Console Output:

```
console.log(zones);
console.log(zone);
```

[image]

Thanks for any input.

Comment: Arrays are objects. If you're using typescript you should be adding type annotations.

Comment: You wrote: "For sure the zones parameter in the reduce function is an array..." how do you know that for sure? The runtime seems to disagree.

Comment: It's odd for sure that the runtime thinks zones is not an array. The following jsBin shows that it ought to work. http://jsbin.com/zukojov/edit?js,console

Comment: I did and its an array. That was the first think I checked. I updated the post with an image of the console.log of the results. The zones array is being passed in the reduce method as the second parameter.